# RSI period length on higher timeframes using request.security needs a multiplier

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Just wanted to confirm something I noticed but no one is talking about it. Seems to me that we need to add a multiplier on a period of an indicator sur as RSI, MACD, SMA, etc when calculating on a higher time frame.

Example: lets say I want to calculate the 14 period 1H RSI on a 15 min chart. I will use request.security to pull the data. In all tutorials they would recommend something like this :

```
// Prevent repainting function
nonRepaintingSecurity(sym, tf, src) =>
    request.security(sym, tf, src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

highTFClose = nonRepaintingSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, "60", close)
rsi_value = ta.rsi(highTFClose, 14) // Seems to give results of a period of 14/4 (because 4x15min => 1h)
```

This seems to give a result of a period of 14/4 because 60min / 15 => 4. Each loop will be triggered at the 15min candle close, so there will be 4 times the same value sent to the ta.rsi calculation.

Lets say the last 4 data points of the 1H close are: 100, 102, 101, 105. Seems to me that ta.rsi will receive theses datapoints during the same period: 100, 100, 100, 100, 102, 102, 102, 102, 101, 101, 101, 101, 105, 105, 105, 105. So it will receive 4x4 = 16 data points meaning it will cover the full 14 period instead of 4 data points only.

So I fixed it by multipling the period by the amount of times the lower time frame fits in the higher one. in my example this would mean doing this:

```
// Prevent repainting function
nonRepaintingSecurity(sym, tf, src) =>
    request.security(sym, tf, src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

highTFClose = nonRepaintingSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, "60", close)
rsi_value = ta.rsi(highTFClose, 14*4)
```

Since I never found any mention of this issue I would like to get the point of view of other pine coders. Maybe there is an option that I can activate in order to avoid having to do this.

If this is the only way and you also use it and you have a function that would divide the higher timeframe by the lower to get the multiplier don't hesitate to share too.